# How do you calculate a decimal number to 8-bit excess binary?

Tags: binary

For example I have the number `-17`. I know that the binary representation of `17` is: `00010001`, how would you turn that into an 8-bit excess binary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to pick a bias for the excess representation. Since it's typical to select a bias equal to half the available range in magnitude, for 8 bits we 'll pick -127 as the bias.

What this means is that you have 8 bits which will be interpreted as an unsigned integer and 127 will be subtracted from that integer to get the final result. Therefore, since we have

```
final = unsigned + bias
final = -17
bias  = -127
```

We end up with

```
unsigned = final - bias = -17 - (-127) = 110
```

Therefore the excess-127 representation of -17 would be 01101110 (decimal 110).

Comment: If 110 and -17 have the same binary representation, how do you differentiate between them?

Comment: @rockydgeekgod: You don't -- you absolutely must know the "representation rules" in addition to having the raw data. A somewhat-related example: if I tell you "there are 10 kinds of people", how do you know that 10 is decimal ten and not binary two?